# In wp_list_comments(), what is a short_ping?

Tags: comments

I've been looking at [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) for `wp_list_comments()`. One of the options is 'short_ping' which is documented thus:

> ( boolean ) Whether you want to use a short ping.

What on earth is a "short ping" and why would I want one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This option is used to output a pingback comment. It's passed to the `Walker_Comment` class, and if it's set to true, it will output something similar to this:

```
<li>
    <div class="comment-body">
        Pingback: <a href="author-url-here" rel="external nofollow" class="url">Author Name</a>
    </div>
```

The author URL is the field that users enter when filling out the comment form. Note that the closing `</li>` is missing intentionally.